# Awk files installation issue

Tags: apt

I am a new user and working on NS2 for my masters project, need guidance!
I have used these commands to install gawk in NS2

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gawk
```

but I am facing an issue while installing gawk have a look.

```
ak@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install gawk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  gawk-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gawk
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 48 not upgraded.
Need to get 418 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,708 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 gawk amd64 1:5.0.1+dfsg-1
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gawk/gawk_5.0.1+dfsg-1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you have a Network/DNS problem, the error indicates that your system isn't able to resolve us.archive.ubuntu.com.  Try pinging us.archive.ubuntu.com and see if your system can resolve the name and if you get responses eg

```
ping us.archive.ubuntu.com
PING us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.38) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from banjo.canonical.com (91.189.91.38): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=120 ms
```

If this fails then you need to look at your network settings